# What if the query parameter has "&" and while reading the query parameter from the url it declares a new parameter after &?

Tags: angular, url, url-routing

The following query needs to have only two parameters param1 and param2, but since the param2 has & in it so the URL treats it as a third parameter.... how do I avoid it?

```
http://localhost:4200/?department=%CE%95lectrical%20&%20Electronics%20Engineering=&subject=Numerical%20Methods%20&%20Programming=
```

Answer (score 0):

1)you can slove this by base64() encoding and decoding the value in GET page
2)Or you can simply replace the (&) with (%26) when building url.